# Regex for Uppercase Letters, Numbers and dashes only

Tags: regex, vba

I have struggled with this expression for 2 days now so I thought I'd ask for some proper help from the world of knowledge. I hope someone can help.

This is the RegEx I built to get me what I want.

```
\S*\d*?-[A-Z]*[0-9]*
```

I only want the Uppercase Letters and Numbers with dashes, so it does get `GC-113`, `AO-1-GC-113`, `AO-2-GC-113`, which is great!

"I don't want this `------`, but this is good `GC-113`, `AO-1-GC-113`, `AO-2-GC-113`"

BUT if I come across one where there is no space between the number, but just another character like a comma or a period then it returns a match on the entire section "`GC-113,AO-1-GC-113,AO-2-GC-113`"

"I don't want this `------`, but this is good `GC-113,AO-1-GC-113,AO-2-GC-113`"

I'm using RegExBuddy to try and figure this out.

This is the VBA code I'm using get the matches.

```
Public Function GetRIs(ByVal vstrInString As String) As Collection
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Dim myMatches As Variant
Dim myMatch As Variant

Set GetRIs = New Collection
Set myRegExp = New RegExp

myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "\S*\d*?-[A-Z]*[0-9]*"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(vstrInString)

For Each myMatch In myMatches
    If myMatch.Value <> "" Then
        GetRIs.Add myMatch.Value
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: I feel you are looking for [`\w+(?:-\w+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/hK4tZ2/1)

Comment: @DaveStuart - edit your original post with the VBA code. Also I've formatted your question. If anything is formatted incorrectly (the "I don't want this [...]"), please format it correctly.

Comment: Wiktor, that one gets ALL text. I'm looking for a more specific regex to get pull these 3 combinations out GC-113,AO-1-GC-113,AO-2-GC-113.

Comment: Do you mean you just want a [`[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/hK4tZ2/3)? A tip: when you address a SO user in a comment, always add `@` before the user name so that the user gets notified of a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\S*\d*?-[A-Z]*[0-9]*` pattern can even match a single hyphen as only `-` is obligatory and the rest of subpatterns can match zero times (can be absent from the string).

You can use

```
myRegExp.Pattern = "\b[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+"
```

The [pattern matches](https://regex101.com/r/bG9cD8/1):

- `\b` - a word boundary (before the next letter or digit there must be a non-word character or start of string
- `[A-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[A-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters or digits

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! That working perfectly and also thank you for explaining everything so clearly as well.